# WeChat open platform openId and unionId

Tags: oauth, wechat

I want to implement the login with WeChat. While reading the documentation, I came across two different parameters whose meaning I don't fully understand: openId and unionId.

Could someone explain what these id's really are? As far as I understood it should be like this:

- openId - **some** unique id of the user that could change from time to time
- unionId - **the** unique id of the user, the only one that is always the same. Equivalent to the unique id the Google returns when logging in using Google API.

The documentation I read can be found here: http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/web/login/getting-user-profile#login_getting-user-profile

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my understanding, a user's open ids vary from web apps to apps, whereas union id stays the same. For example, you have two apps that use wechat login: W1 and W2. A user will have openid1 for W1 and oepnid2 for W2 seperately, but you can use the user's union id the uniquely identify him/her across the apps.

Open id only changes when you have more than one web/mobile apps.

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Yap, that was my conclusion as well in the end. Thanks :)

Comment: question then is why would anyone want to use an openID?

Comment: @dcsan I'd like to know that too

Comment: From Chinese docs (with google translate) it says: _If and only if the mobile application has been `userinfo` authorized user, this field will appear_.  
But I'm not sure what that means

Answer (score 3):

"why would anyone want to use an openID" - that is a very good question from @dcsan.

从api来讲的话，最大区别就是 unionId 需要 openId 和 access_token 去取得，也就是多了一个auth step。

从实用角度来看，openId更多起了一种 data anonymization 的作用。

除此之外 from what I understand,

<s>openId = f(unionId, appId) where f是一个hash function，etc。</s>

Update, it's probably something more like=

```
openid = f(userId, appId) 
unionid = f(userId, appOwnerId)
```

where f是一个hash function

Answer (score 0):

When your company have more than one official account, one same user follow both of them, the open id for one user are different. To solve this issue, wechat develop the union id to help identify different openid but same user.